# Why CreateWindowEx returns NULL when using WNDCLASSEX and RegisterClassEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

So this is like the code from docs.microsoft but I decided to use WNDCLASSEX and RegisterClassEx instead. When running, the app closes itself inmediately and no window is showed. When Debugging I found out that the CreateWindowEx function returns a NULL value. Note that if I use WNDCLASS and RegisterClass, CreateWindowEx returns a normal value an it shows the window as intended.

What does WNDCLASSEX and RegisterClassEx do in comparisson to WNDCLASS and RegisterClass and how this affects CreateWindowEx? I would like to understand the reason of this behavior.

This is the code. Thanks a lot in advanced!

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR pCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the windows class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                                                  // Optional window styles.                  
        CLASS_NAME,                                         // Window class
        L"Sorting Algorithm Simulator",                     // Window name
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,           // Window style

        // position and size
        400, 200, 640, 480,

        NULL,       // Parent window                
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM  lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);



        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: [*"To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa#return-value). You are not checking the return value of `RegisterClassExA` either.

Comment: Also, make sure you call `GetLastError` immediately after you call the function returning the failure code.  The reason is that you do not want to chance having the error code cleared by calling an intervening API function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegisterClassEx()` needs to know the size of the structure you are using, so you have to initialize the member wc.cbSize with `sizeof(wc)`:

```
wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
```

Or equivalently:

```
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) ;
```

Comment: `wc.cbSize = sizeof wc;` - parentheses are necessary for type, with structure they are redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
wc.cbSize = sizeof wc;
```

and zero out the rest of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the documentation for [WNDCLASSEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw):

> The `WNDCLASSEX` structure is similar to the [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassw) structure. There are two differences. `WNDCLASSEX` includes the `cbSize` member, which specifies the size of the structure [...]

The documentation for `cbSize` has this information:

> The size, in bytes, of this structure. Set this member to `sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)`. [...]

In the absence of error checking code you're going to have to make sure to write perfect code. A step towards that goal is to properly initialize the `WNDCLASSEX` structure. The `cbSize` member is the first member in structures, if present. The following zero-initializes the structure, and sets the `cbSize` member appropriately:

```cpp
WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(wc) };
```

although I'd prefer

```cpp
WNDCLASSEXW wc = { sizeof(wc) };
```

---

Important lessons:

- Read the documentation, thoroughly.
- Implement error reporting/handling.

Comment: The documentation is not helpful on this one. Right after the *Set this member to `sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)`*, there is *Be sure to set this member before calling the `GetClassInfoEx` function*, which makes it sound like it's not important to set it before calling `RegisterClassEx`.

Comment: @gse: If you find that the documentation is inaccurate or misleading, you can [propose a change](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw.md).